# Select first row in overlapping records

Tags: sql, netezza, date-range

Consider the following table:

```
ID  From        To
1   07.06.2015  07.06.2015
2   03.01.2016  19.01.2016
3   05.01.2016  20.01.2016
4   19.01.2016  24.01.2016
5   20.01.2016  24.01.2016
6   24.01.2016  24.01.2016
7   11.03.2016  27.03.2016
```

How would I go about selecting only 
a) the rows that have no overlapping records or
b) the first row in a series of overlapping records?

For the above example, I would want to retain records 1 and 7 (they have no overlaps) and 2 and 5 (3 and 4 overlap 2, and 6 overlaps 5):

```
ID  From        To
1   07.06.2015  07.06.2015
2   03.01.2016  19.01.2016
5   20.01.2016  24.01.2016
7   11.03.2016  27.03.2016
```

PS: I'm on Netezza, so a recursive query is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.from < t.from and t2.to > t.from
                 );
```

Note:  This assumes that the `from` dates are distinct.  If there can be duplicates, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.from <= t.from and
                        t2.id < t.id and
                        t2.to > t.from
                 );
```

Comment: It's close, but this gives me ids 1, 2, 6, 7, that is 6 in stead of 5.

Comment: But "5" intersects with "4", so it doesn't meet your condition.

Comment: Sorry if my description was unprecise. Since "4" intersects with "2", "4" is "disqualified". I guess the goal is to select all records that do not intersect with any preceding records that does not intersect with any preceding records (and so on). I'm not sure if such a sequential logic is possible in SQL?